# How do I split a string on non-traditional white-space?

Tags: ruby, regex, tabs, whitespace

Ruby 2.4.  I want to split a line by multiple white spaces, that is more than one single breaking or non-breaking space, or white space that is not a single space (like a tab or a new line).  I tried the below

```
tokens_by_spaces = line.split(/\s\s+/)
```

but this fails.  For example if line is

```
"A B\tC D"
```

the above returns

```
["A B\tC D"]
```

whereas I want it to return

```
["A B", "C D"]
```

Similarly, if my line was

```
"ab c  def g"
```

I would want the result to be

```
["ab c", "def g"]
```

Comment: Try `line.split(/[\s&&[^ ]]+| {2,}/)`

Comment: Well, or maybe `/[ \u00A0]*(?:[\s&&[^ \u00A0]][ \u00A0]*)+|\s{2,}/` if you mean a string should be split with a chunk of whitespaces that cannot be just spaces/nonbreaking space or *any* 2 or more whitespaces.

Comment: Gold.  You are the regular expression Yoda.

Comment: So, which one works? Actually, I do not fully understand the requirements.

Comment: They both do although I went with the second one as it seems to account for non-breaking spaces and as I undertand it, "\s" does not account for non-breaking spaces.

Comment: Well, it seems you may use `(?u)` at the start of the pattern, and `/(?u)\s+/` will  match any Unicode whitespace. Maybe you need `/(?u)[ \u00A0]*(?:[\s&&[^ \u00A0]][ \u00A0]*)+|\s{2,}/`?

Comment: @Wiktor, cannot your second regex be simplified to `/[\s&&[^ ]]+|[ \u00A0]{2,}/`, considering that `\s` does not match `\u00A0` (only space, tab (`\t`), newline (`\n`), linefeed (`\r`), form feed (`\f`) and vertical tab (`\v`))? See "character classes [here](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Regexp.html) for this list. `\v` appears to have been added in v2.3.

Comment: @CarySwoveland: That is why I actually was a bit unsure of the requirements. Anyway, I decided to go with `[:space:]`.

Comment: It be a little ludicrous to tell what a whitespace is, best to leave it to an implementation that uses  \s. Basically it's a simple `[^\S ]+|[ ]{2,}` to answer your question.

Comment: In utf-16 terms this would translate into `[\u0009-\u000D\u0085\u00A0\u1680\u2000-\u200A\u2028-\u2029\u202F\u205F\u3000]+|[ ]{2,}` see how simp it is ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest using

```
/[ \u00A0]*(?:[[:space:]&&[^ \u00A0]][ \u00A0]*)+|[[:space:]]{2,}/
```

See the [regex demo](http://rubular.com/r/ojYe7ktwKS).

Although it seems `\s` can match any Unicode whitespace if the pattern is prepended with `(?u)`, `[[:space:]]` seems to be a more adopted way to match any Unicode whitespace.

**Details**:

The pattern has 2 branches that match either...

- `[ \u00A0]*(?:[[:space:]&&[^ \u00A0]][ \u00A0]*)+` - a chunk of whitespaces that contain at least 1 non-space/non-nonbreaking space

  - `[ \u00A0]*` - zero or more occurrences of a regular or non-breaking spaces
  - `(?:[[:space:]&&[^ \u00A0]][ \u00A0]*)+` - one or more occurrences of:

    - `[[:space:]&&[^ \u00A0]]` - (a character class subtraction) any whitespace with the exception of a regular/non-breaking whitespace
    - `[ \u00A0]*` - zero or more regular/non-breaking whitespaces
- `|` - or
- `[[:space:]]{2,}`  - 2 or more any whitespace symbols